# Adding href link to a bug entry?

Tags: doxygen

I'm attempting to include links to bug reporting tools in the bug list.  The following doesn't work and doesn't even generate a bug list entry.  Thinking I'm missing something basic.

**In the config:**

`ALIASES += JIRA{1}="\bug \1 <a href=\"https://jira/browse/\"\1>\1</a>"`

**In the code:**

`/// @JIRA XX-12345`

The result is just plain comments, no links and no bug list.

Comment: Bah.  The link text was mangled.  Have no doubt, the link is properly formed.

Comment: Thanks Max.  That's much more readable than my botched attempt.

Comment: Please review the manual chapter 15. Looking at this case the "In code" part is missing {}. The \\bug should only have 1 backslash , there is no terminating double quote for the https part and the closing tag of the <a> should have a / and not a backslash.

Comment: I added the double \ for bug was my fevered attempt to get it to work, thinking that I needed to escape the contents of the string.  Also, the {1} is for defining a parameter to an alias, no?  And parameters are space delimited?

Comment: Ok, so parameters to custom commands are _not_ delimited by spaces.   I knew I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, the proper form I was looking for is:

*In the config:*

`ALIASES                = JIRA{1}="\bug <a href=\"https://jira/browse/\1\">\1</a>"`

*In the code:*

`\\\ @JIRA{ XX-1234 }`